# How to join multiple tSortRow into one tFileOutputExcel

Tags: talend

I have to do a job with Talend, but I'm a beginner and the software is very complex, I'm a bit lost.

My current problem is to join multiple  `tSplitRow` into one output excel file.

I don't know if I must use `tMap`? How to configure it? Or if another object exist to do that.

Each `tSplitRow` has the same structure: `LastName,FirstName,Course,Grade`.

**My current structure**

[image]

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your components have the same structure, you can use `tUnite` to do a union of your rows. It takes multiple input links, and has a single output.

Comment: Thank's again! Can you tell me how you know that? Which doc are you using? You saved me...

Comment: Great ;) Don't worry, when you have worked through a few Talend projects, you'll get to know different components and what they do :)
There are numerous Talend tutorials online to get you started, here's one: https://community.talend.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/Tutorials

Comment: Thanks to you I can do a great work! Thank's again! I will check that :D